# Override attachment on object by using apex

Tags: apex

I need to override attachment on object by using apex.I wrote an Apex class but Here attachment override but I got some error on debug:
FATAL_ERROR|System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable: Attachment.ParentId

Here my Apex class:

```
global class quotePdfGeneratorController {

    webService static void saveAndClosePdf(String quoteId){ 
        init(quoteId);        
    }  


     global static void init(String quoteId){
        system.debug('===SaveAndClose quote===> '+quoteId);               
        Blob content;
        PageReference pdf = Page.CreateQuote;
        pdf.getParameters().put('id',quoteId);
        system.debug('--pdf-->'+pdf);

        if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
            content = pdf.getContentAsPDF();        
        }else{
            content = blob.valueof('Some Test');
        }
        System.debug('content ==>'+content );
        /*
        QuoteDocument doc = new QuoteDocument(Document = content, QuoteId = quoteId);
        Database.SaveResult insertResult = Database.Insert(doc, false);
        system.debug('--doc-->'+doc);
        */
        Quote quoteObj = [Select id,QuoteNumber,Quote_PDF_Number__c from Quote where id =: quoteId];
        List<QuoteDocument> quoteDoc = new List<QuoteDocument>([Select id from QuoteDocument where QuoteId =: quoteId]);

        system.debug('===quoteDoc===> '+quoteDoc);
        if(quoteDoc != null && quoteDoc.size()>0){
            Integer docNum = quoteDoc.size();
            docNum ++;
            quoteObj.Quote_PDF_Number__c  = '_V'+docNum;
        }else{
            quoteObj.Quote_PDF_Number__c  = '_V1';
        }

            Blob body;
            try {
                body = content; 

            } catch (VisualforceException e) {
                body = Blob.valueOf('Some Text');
            }

                Document d = new Document();
                    d.FolderId = UserInfo.getUserId();
                    d.Body = body;
                    d.name = quoteObj.QuoteNumber+'.pdf';
                    d.ContentType = 'application/pdf';
                    d.Type = 'pdf';
                    d.IsPublic = true;
                    insert d;

                System.debug('d==>'+d);

                Attachment a = new Attachment();
                    a.parentId = quoteId;
                    a.Body = content;
                    a.Name = quoteObj.QuoteNumber+'_'+datetime.now()+'.pdf';
                    a.ContentType = 'application/pdf'; 
                    insert a;    
             List<Attachment> atch = [Select Id,Name,Description,LastModifiedDate,Body from Attachment where ParentId =: quoteId LIMIT 1];
             system.debug('atch -->' +atch);        
             delete atch;

              if(a.Body == Null && a.Name == Null)
                   {
                    if(atch != null && atch.size() > 0){

                    system.debug('attachment2 -->' +a);
                        a.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
                        a.ParentId = quoteId; //specify the record ID;
                        a.IsPrivate = true;

                        a.Name = atch[0].Name;
                        a.Body = atch[0].Body;

                        insert a;
                    }
            }
           else{

                        system.debug('attachment 1 -->' +a);
                        system.debug('atch[0].Name -->' +atch[0].Name);
                        system.debug('atch[0].Body -->' +atch[0].Body);

                        a.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
                        a.ParentId = quoteId; //specify the record ID;
                        a.IsPrivate = true;

                        insert a;

           }
     }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Associating an attachment with a custom object](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44567/associating-an-attachment-with-a-custom-object)

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
insert a;
```

very soon after:

```
Attachment a = new Attachment();
```

which means your later attempt to set the `ParentId` will fail.

Removing that first `insert a;` so you can modify the parent because the object has not been inserted (and relying on the later inserts to do the insert) looks like it would fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer of my questions now it works fine.

Apex class:

```
        List < Attachment > atch = [Select Id, Name, Description, LastModifiedDate, Body from Attachment where ParentId = : quoteId LIMIT 1];
        if (atch.size() > 0) {
            delete atch;
        }
        system.debug('atch -->' + atch);

        Attachment a = new Attachment();
        a.parentId = quoteId;
        a.Body = content;
        a.Name = quoteObj.QuoteNumber + '_' + datetime.now() + '.pdf';
        a.ContentType = 'application/pdf';
        insert a;
        system.debug('a -->' + a);
```

Comment: It would be much more useful to the forum if instead of just posting the entire chunk of code (which has irrelevant functionality), try to post something concise and instructive. What is the one change you made? Deleting the old attachments and inserting new ones? Maybe write something about that instead of just dumping everything in here.

Comment: Thanks adrian for giving me a suggestion :)
First I am deleting my existing attachment then insert new one.